# Use self type as return type in Scala trait

Tags: scala, traits, type-systems

I would like to define a trait which uses the type of the concrete class which extends it as a return type in one of its abstract methods. Is this possible in Scala (2.13)? For example, the following doesn't compile because I can't find a way to bind the `ConcreteType`:

```scala
trait Shape
trait Growable {
  def grow() : ConcreteType
}
case class Circle(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape with Growable {
  def grow() : Circle = this.copy(size = size + 1)
}
case class Square(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape with Growable {
  def grow() : Square = this.copy(size = size + 1)
}
```

I achieved something close with the following code:

```scala
trait Shape
trait Growable[T <: Shape] {
  def grow() : T
}
case class Circle(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape with Growable[Circle] {
  def grow() : Circle = this.copy(size = size + 1)
}
case class Square(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape with Growable[Square] {
  def grow() : Square = this.copy(size = size + 1)
}
```

Then a user of this code would use it like this:

```
val circle : Circle = Circle(0, 0, 10).grow()
val square : Square = Square(0, 0, 10).grow()
// or
val shapes : Seq[Shape] = List(circle, square).map(_.grow())
```

I would like to avoid having to pass in the type via generics, that seems redundant. Any ideas for how to accomplish this?

Comment: I am surprised the amount of _"incorrect"_ answers, given this is a really common question in **Scala**. [This blog post from Rob Norris](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) explains the problem and solution in detail. - TL;DR; The simplest solution is to use **F-Bounded** polymorphism _(which is similar to your solution)_, but it is not completely safe. The best solution is to use **typeclasses** instead of **subtype** polymorphism. - BTW, if you are interested, I wrote a simple [article](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4) comparing those two

Comment: Note that, Mario's answer includes the **typeclasses** approach I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [shapeless lenses](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/lenses.scala) approach

```
import shapeless._

sealed trait Shape
case class Circle(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape
case class Square(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape

implicit val circleLens = lens[Circle].size
implicit val squareLens = lens[Square].size

implicit class GrowableShape[T <: Shape](shape: T) {
  def grow()(implicit shapeLense: Lens[T, Int]): T =
    shapeLense.modify(shape)(_ + 1)
}

Circle(0, 0, 10).grow()
Square(0, 0, 10).grow()
```

which outputs

```
res0: Circle = Circle(0,0,11)
res1: Square = Square(0,0,11)
```

Alternatively consider a typeclass solution using vanilla scala

```
trait Growable[T <: Shape] {
  def grow(shape: T): T
}

sealed trait Shape
case class Circle(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape
case class Square(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape

implicit val circleGrowable = new Growable[Circle] {
  def grow(shape: Circle): Circle = shape.copy(size = shape.size + 1)
}

implicit val squareGrowable = new Growable[Square] {
  def grow(shape: Square): Square = shape.copy(size = shape.size + 1)
}

implicit class GrowableShape[T <: Shape](shape: T) {
  def grow()(implicit growable: Growable[T]): T =
    growable.grow(shape)
}

Circle(0, 0, 10).grow()
Square(0, 0, 10).grow()
```

which outputs

```
res0: Circle = Circle(0,0,11)
res1: Square = Square(0,0,11)
```

Comment: I think you need a good reason, to justify all this implicits. Also it makes it harder to understand, where your `grow` method comes from. Even if this seems like a nice solution, I would not use it, if I expect other (future) developers that are not that experienced have to read it.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest way, since, scala methods/function result type is covariance in nature i.e. `() => Growable` is supertype of `() => Circle` or `() => Square`, you can simply do as below by explicitly providing concrete type in implementation:

```
  trait Shape
  trait Growable {
    def grow() : Growable
  }
  case class Circle(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape with Growable {
    def grow() : Circle = this.copy(size = size + 1)
  }
  case class Square(x : Int, y : Int, size : Int) extends Shape with Growable {
    def grow() : Square = this.copy(size = size + 1)
  }
```

Comment: While this works for simple cases, it will not have the desired semantics when combined with more abstract methods. Like try yo write a generic method `doubleGrow` which receives any `Shape` and returns the same type of `Shape` but after calling `grow` twice.